# RxAndroid Emitter disposed without complete/error

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am having an issue using RxJava on Android to read from async I/O. I create a Flowable and subscribe to an emitter. It works the first time, calling onNext and then onComplete when finished, but when I try the same operations again(create a new Flowable and subscribe), I get an UndeliverableException if I intentionally throw an I/O error. If I do an emitter.isCancelled, it returns true. Not sure why this happens.

```
Flowable getFlowable(){

  Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<Object> emitter) throws Exception {

      getIOResponse(new IOListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(Object ioResponse) {
          emitter.onNext(ioResponse);
          emitter.onComplete();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {                      
          emitter.onError(e);   //Throws UndeliverableException, emitter already cancelled

        }
      }
    }
  }
}

static void subscribe(){
    disposable = getFlowable()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .timeout(TIME_OUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(Object myObject) throws Exception {
        someListener.onSuccess(myObject);

      }
    }, throwable -> {
      someListener.onError(throwable);
    }, () -> {
      Log.d("****", "Completed");
    });
}
```

Comment: How is your `Exception` caught and propagated to your `IOListener`? Also why do you have `someListener` seems unnecessary delegation in the `subscribe`

Comment: Where do you dispose that `disposable`? Perhaps put a breakpoint in that location to see what's calling it.

Comment: @akarnokd I do not explicitly dispose of the disposable. My understanding is calling onComplete or onError will do that for you. I did try to explicitly call it after a complete or error and it made no difference.

Comment: @MarkKeen Exception is caught in a separate handler thread that is dealing with the I/O. That calls the onError of the Listener. SomeListener just propagates the returned object up to another layer.

Comment: A fresh `emitter` should not be immediately disposed, unless you somehow reuse an earlier `emitter` reference. Are you sure you posted the code that is supposed to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: If you're already using handler threads, listeners/callbacks why are you using RxJava in the first place? Essentially you have asynchronous callbacks wrapped in asynchronous Rx code?

Comment: @akarnokd Wrapped subscribe code to make referencing easier. This is definitely the code. To clarify I am calling subscribe, getting one result from I/O, calling onNext, onComplete, then sometime later calling subscribe again. If we remove the handler thread from I/O and mock it up to call oninfo/onerror synchronously everything seem to work fine. Is it possible something inside getIOResponse could cause problems?

Comment: I have no way of knowing that since I can't see into your codebase.